# How to test if a pandas Series is contained in the rows of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a pandas Series and I want to test if it corresponds exactly to a row of a pandas DataFrame

### Example of expected behaviour

`s in df` ==> `True`
where `s = pd.Series({'a': 1, 'b': 2})` and `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [2,1,3]})`

`s in df` ==> `False`
where `s = pd.Series({'a': 1, 'b': 2})` and `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2,1,3], 'b': [1,3,4]})`

### Solution I know that works but very difficult to read

```py
not df[(df['a'] == s['a']) & (df['b'] == s['b'])].empty
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is compare by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html), then test if at least one match by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and then test by [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html):

Here is added [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for filter columns only by `Series` `s`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [2,1,3], 'c': [4,5,48]})
print (df)
   a  b   c
0  1  2   4
1  2  1   5
2  3  3  48

s = pd.Series({'a': 1, 'b': 2})

print (df.reindex(s.index, axis=1))
   a  b
0  1  2
1  2  1
2  3  3

print (df.reindex(s.index, axis=1).eq(s))
       a      b
0   True   True
1  False  False
2  False  False

print (df.reindex(s.index, axis=1).eq(s).all(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool

print (df.reindex(s.index, axis=1).eq(s).all(axis=1).any())
True
```

Comment: @user11696358 - One thing, it is good sample data? Ot you think `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [2,20,3]})` ?

Comment: you are right sample data was incorrect, I corrected it